# Bash concatenate strings results in each variable within quotes

Tags: bash

I am trying to concatenate 2 variables into a string in Bash. I have seen a lot of posts on this and for some reason they don't work for me. Here is my script which just takes a file name prefix and adds the current date to the end.

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +”%Y%m%d”)
fname=“file”
x=$fname$now
echo $x
```

This results in `"file""20150316"` instead of the desired `"file20150316"`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Replace the `"` with nothing `${a//"/}`. `x="${fname//"/}${now//"/}`

Comment: Those aren't normal quotes in your input they are smart quotes (or something). So the shell just treats them as characters. Remove them entirely or replace them with normal ascii quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using wrong quotes (unicode ones not the actual ASCII ones). Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
fname="file"
x="$fname$now"
echo "$x"
```

Comment: None of the first three lines here actually need the quotes, just for the record.

Comment: Oh yes that is true, it is not required to use quotes every where but always a safe practice in shell.

Comment: @EtanReisner I guess the fourth line doesn't need quotes either, if you take the first three lines literally. ;)